# Deleting unuseful comments!

Tags: discussion, comments

On many posts, there are comments like "add sources" or "what about ....??"or ....

Most of these comments ask for an edit or sth but even after the request being accomplished they are still there, It makes it so hard to follow the post and actually understand what's going on!!

I do want this to be decided upon and possibly recommend high rep users to delete such not at all usefulness comments!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These comments should be flagged as *obsolete*. The moderators will look into it and have them deleted.

Comments can only be deleted by moderators.

If it gains enough flags it will [automatically](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/650/why-are-comments-deleted#comment1727_651) be deleted.

*Tada.*

Comment: And I guess it would be also nice if everyone cleans after himself too!

Comment: That would be an added responsibility which the community could take up at large.