# How can I recover the old answers and comments after editing?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, editing, comments

I want to know if there is a way to restore back the answers and comments?After you have edited?And how can I recover an deleted comment I guess?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If it is your answer or question then you can use the undelete link or button (unless it was not you whom deleted it) if it was not yours you can only address a mod (diamond user) to help you out or post a meta post. Comments can't be "undeleted" as they have a rather temporary function and should basically help improving an answer or a post in general not answer questions! See https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/answers-on-comment-section and https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/deleting-unuseful-comments

Comment: Then how come when I edited the question title and the question from the box then the comments are deleted?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I meant on answers

Comment: If we go ahead chatting with each other via comment, we at a time will get an automatic order to continue in chat. Comments are not meant to be kept, so they might sooner or later be deleted by the community bot or a mod if he finds reasons to intervene. That's why we have the possibility to create chat room to discuss.

Comment: Also take a look at https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: @Medi1Saif Why would it be deleted the comments?It could be helpful for others to know,right?

Answer (score 1):

There's an "undelete" button to undelete answers (although this might be unavailable, e.g. if a diamond moderator deletes the answer).

Deleted comments are gone.  This is by design; see the [Comment Everywhere](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) help page:

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

Basically, this is a question and answer site; not a comment site.